# Explain the output of uname(1)

Tags: linux, kernel

I am a FreeBSD user, and in the latest numberic release of FreeBSD, the output of `uname -v` is this:

```
FreeBSD 12.1-RELEASE-p10 GENERIC
```

Which according to the manual page, Writes the version level of this release of the operating system to standard output.

But I have noticed in GNU/Linux operating systems `uname -v` is written something like this:

```
#24+system76~1573659475~19.04~26b2022-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 13 20:0
```

[Shot From This Source](https://linuxhandbook.com/uname/)

I know it shows the kernel version and last compile time, but I am mostly here for the:

```
#24
```

part which I have currently found no explained reason for its existence. What is this for?

Comment: This [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124466/what-is-the-difference-of-kernel-distributions-release-and-version) is related. Actually the -r (release) is the "Linux kernel version" plus some more (distribution depended), the -v is some kind of version tag from the distribution while building the package, I suspect this first number is some index (?) possibly they number the builds out of their same kernel release.

Comment: A more general question about the whole string is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/136959/5132 .